# Check if cast to int will lose data - PHP

Tags: php, casting, biginteger

I have this piece of code:

```
$result = new stdClass();
foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
    if(is_numeric($value)){
        $int = (int)$value;
        $double = (double)$value;
        if($int == $double)
            $value = $int;
        else
            $value = $double;
    }
    $index = strtolower($index);
    $result->$index = $value;
}
```

And it worked for ages. Now I got a problem with it. I have a column in my database that has numbers (big numbers) in it. But they're not numbers, they're `varchar` and those numbers are not for mathematical purpose. Unfortunately, since the column is fully filled with numbers only, it passes the `is_numeric` test, but since it's a giant number, it loses data due to memory limitation (4 billions, I think).
Anyway, how can I check if after the cast I lost data or not to my variable?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
if($value<=PHP_INT_MAX) ... // safe to convert
else // not safe
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it back and see if it gives the same value as the source.